# Multiple apache and finding its ports

Tags: linux, apache

The following command

```
[cuser@vdev-b7-5461-4f3c-9d98-7fc3ec6 kafka]$ ps aux|grep apache
apache    3967  0.0  0.0 175412  3192 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3968  0.0  0.0 175412  3192 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3969  0.0  0.0 175412  3192 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3970  0.0  0.0 175412  3192 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3971  0.0  0.0 175276  2700 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3972  0.0  0.0 175276  2700 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3974  0.0  0.0 175412  3188 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
apache    3975  0.0  0.0 175276  2696 ?        S    03:40   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
clduser   9566  0.0  0.0 103244   844 pts/1    S+   16:41   0:00 grep apache
```

There are multiple apache process running in my machine. Is there a way for me to determine the files/directory each of these process uses to run it?

Also, would like to know the ports that they are using?

```
[user@vdev-37-5461-4f3c-9d98-7af28dfc3ec6 kafka]$ netstat -tulpn|grep 80
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=500 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

This above command shows port 80 is being used but I want to know what process is using it?

```
[duser@vpsq-dev-4ac0b737-5461-4f3c-9d98-7af28dfc3ec6 kafka]$ find / -iname apache 2>/dev/null
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jruby-kafka-1.4.0-java/lib/org/apache
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/org/apache
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jruby-kafka-1.1.2-java/lib/org/apache
/home/duser/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/org/apache
/home/duser/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jruby-kafka-1.1.2-java/lib/org/apache
```

Comment: there will be only one actual instance of apache running, but ps shows each thread as a separate line. Your ps output is missing the process  that started them all, because the user is root. Use `ps aux | grep httpd` to see better. You need to be root to get the full process id from netstat.

Comment: @chris: using sudo worked now I got the PID using the netstat command..but the process id does not tell where the program location is --root      1557  0.0  0.0 175276  4112 ?        Ss    2015  20:37 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start

Comment: It just says /usr/sbin/httpd..I want to get the actual location where the process is kicked off.

Comment: My grep command(given above) list multiple installation of apache, I want to know which one is currently running.

Comment: Those aren't multiple installations. Those are threads. There will be one process run by root, which kicks off all those threads (run by the apache user, with lower privileges). The executable is /usr/sbin/httpd.

Comment: The multiple installation I meant is the number of apache folders being listed in the "find" command that I have added now..sorry for the confusion

Comment: None of those are installations of apache. They are ruby gems relating to apache logs (or something). The actual apache executable is called httpd, and is at /usr/sbin/httpd